# Maven WAR Plugin / Jenkins repository connector: Omitting transitive dependencies?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, war

**Situation**

I have a multi-module Maven project. In it, I have several JAR artefacts, it then gets assembled as a WAR file. Thus, the WAR artefact depends on all kinds of JAR artefacts (it also has a WAR overlay), most of them with scope "compile".

Build and deployment to a repository are fine. But when I try to retrieve the WAR artefact, I have issues. previously, I used a simple wget to retrieve it from the Nexus API, but I wanted to try the Jenkins Repository Connector - not the least reason being that it actually shows a list of available versions.

I configure a repository in

```
Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Artifact Resolver
```

with the URL for our repo:

```
http://$NEXUS/nexus/content/repositories/releases/
```

then in the job, i add a parameter:

```
Maven Repository Artifact
```

and use the repository configured above, then i add

```
Artifact Resolver
```

as a build step and set it up.

**Problem**

I am not even sure on which side this should be solved: When I run the job to try to get the WAR file from the nexus, it also starts trying to retrieve all kinds of transitive dependencies (some of which are unaccessible to this user) and fails. What I need is just the WAR file. No transitive dependencies (since they're already packaged in the WAR).

The Repository Connector plugin doesn't seem to have a switch for this, and the Maven side it's probably perfectly OK to include those dependencies in the output POM.

**Question**

What can I do to either stop the repository connector from retrieving transitive dependencies or retrieve the WAR artefact in a different way? Also interesting for me (but a bit broad as a question) would be general ideas about doing this kind of workflow. E.g., does anyone use other ways of deploying the WAR *into* their Nexus?

Comment: How did you try to get the war file from nexus? curl? programmatically?

Comment: i used to do curl or wget - this time i tried the jenkins repository connector plugin ... the problem is there is apparently no way to keep it from downloading the transitive dependencies as well ...

Comment: Can you exactly show how you tried it?

Comment: Well - the WAR deployment TO the nexus is normal maven release:perform, and then for retrieving it, i configured a repository in "Manage Jenkins -> Configure Jenkins -> Artifact Resolver", with the URL pointing to: http://out_nexus_host/nexus/content/repositories/releases/

Comment: i then used a "maven repository artifact" parameter, and then as a build step, i used the "Artifact Resolver". When I run it, i see the correct versions listed, and the Artifact Resolver correctly connects to the repository, but then starts downloading the transitive dependencies of the WAR file, some of which are not accessible to the given user, so it fails. What I NEED is just the plain WAR file.

Comment: updated question to include this information

Answer (score 0):

i submitted a patch to the repository connector plugin.

my fork:

https://github.com/rmalchow/repository-connector-plugin

working on getting it to be merged:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/repository-connector-plugin/pull/10